# Validating and linking to another page

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a login page.In whicn iam unable to link it with the next page after clicking submit button.I want to validate and redirect to the next page.ie home.php.Kindly help me find out what am i missing.

signin.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
<script>
function val()
{
var a=document.signin.user.value;
var b=document.signin.password.value;
if ( a == "admin" && b == "rec"){
alert ("Login success");
window.location = "home.php"; 
return false;
}
else{
alert("login failed")
}
}
</script>   
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>LIBRARY </title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="grad"></div>
    <div class="header">
    <div>REC<span>LIBRARY</span></div>
    </div>
    <br>
<br>
<br>
    <div class="login">
<form name="signin" method="post" onsubmit="val();">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="user"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>

<input type="submit" id="mybutton" value="login"></form>
    </div>



    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry about my tag.I just need to validate and then redirect.

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question.  If someone were to look at the page source, wouldn't they be given free access to the correct username and password of admin and rec?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the onsubmit event is not having `false` returned to it, so it posts the form normally, after your JavaScript has finished. Even in the case of successful login and the redirect is executed, the form will still submit and it will override the redirect.

Firstly, Move your `return false;` to the end of the function, so that it always executes.

Secondly, change your `onsubmit="val();"` to `onsubmit="return val();"`. This means the onsubmit event will always be returned `false` and will not try to post the form.

---

Side note: this is by no means a secure system. Any visitor can simply observe the HTML source to find the password, or just navigate directly to home.php. For a secure system, you will need to do the authentication on the server side (in the PHP).

Answer (score 1):

You could use preventDefault() Event method without using onsubmit=val() like below.

```
document.getElementById("signin").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
// actual code to validate
});
```

or

can try some dirty work on server side directly to hide the validation part

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
loginForm();
$userinfo = array(
                'admin'=>'0b2c082c00e002a2f571cbe340644239'
                );
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    if($userinfo[$_POST['username']] == md5($_POST['password'])){
         $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
         header('Location: home.php');
         exit();
    }else{
         ?>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
                alert("Oops.... User name or Pasword is worng, Please try again");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
function loginForm()
{
?>
        <form name="login" action="" method="post">
            Username:  <input type="text" name="username"> <br><br>
            Password:  <input type="password" name="password"><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="login">
        </form>
<?php
}
?>
```